# How to skip a line when using visual block mode?

Tags: neovim, cursor, visual-block

I want to add cursors to all lines except the third, is that achievable?

```
1 
2
3  skip this line
4
5
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. "Add cursors" is not an editing operation. Please [edit] and tell us the real problem you're trying to solve. Maybe the answer does not even need to involve multiple cursors.

Comment: @Friedrich Thanks for asking, the question is indeed about multi-cursors, and I didn't know Vim only supports one cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual mode is strictly contiguous so this is not possible.

Note that visual block mode is *not* equivalent to multiple cursors: you still get only one cursor, which is all Vim can offer.

If you absolutely want multiple cursors, there are a few plugins available that mimic that feature, like [this one](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi) (untested).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know Vim only supports one cursor, does Neovim have the same limitation?

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "limitation" but yes, it does.